# Testing Ionic 3 Lazy Loading Pages with Jest

Tags: typescript, testing, ionic3, jestjs

I am trying to test the contents of my pages now that I have converted them to Lazy Loading with Ionic 3.  However, I constantly get compile errors in the spec.ts file, as I am not sure how to build the individual test bed parts for tab pages in the application.  I am trying to simply test a standard simple page generated with the ionic generate page command.

about.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AboutPage } from './about';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AboutPage,
    ],
    imports: [
        IonicPageModule.forChild(AboutPage),
    ],
})
export class AboutPageModule {}
```

about.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
    selector: 'page-about',
    templateUrl: 'about.html',
})
export class AboutPage {

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad AboutPage');
    }

}
```

Now I am trying to to create the test file:

about.spec.ts

```
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture, async, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { IonicPageModule, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import { AboutPage } from './about';

let comp: AboutPage;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<AboutPage>;

describe('About Page', () => {

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [AboutPage],
            providers: [
                NavController,
                NavParams
            ],
            imports: [
                IonicPageModule.forChild(AboutPage)
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AboutPage);
        comp    = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        fixture.destroy();
        comp = null;
    });

    it('is created', () => {
        expect(fixture).toBeTruthy();
        expect(comp).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Errors:

```
Can't resolve all parameters for NavParams: (?).

  15 |                              NavController,
  16 |                              NavParams
> 17 |             ],
  18 |             imports: [
  19 |                 IonicPageModule.forChild(AboutPage)
  20 |             ]

  at syntaxError (node_modules/packages/compiler/esm5/src/util.js:176:2)
  at CompileMetadataResolver.Object.<anonymous>.CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (node_modules/packages/compiler/esm5/src/metadata_resolver.js:1130:10)
  at CompileMetadataResolver.Object.<anonymous>.CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15425:26)
  at CompileMetadataResolver.Object.<anonymous>.CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableMetadata (node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15405:21)
  at CompileMetadataResolver.Object.<anonymous>.CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (node_modules/packages/compiler/esm5/src/metadata_resolver.js:1305:14)
  at node_modules/packages/compiler/esm5/src/metadata_resolver.js:1216:7
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at CompileMetadataResolver.Object.<anonymous>.CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (node_modules/packages/compiler/esm5/src/metadata_resolver.js:1176:17)
  at CompileMetadataResolver.Object.<anonymous>.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (node_modules/packages/compiler/esm5/src/metadata_resolver.js:744:10)
  at JitCompiler.Object.<anonymous>.JitCompiler._loadModules (node_modules/packages/compiler/esm5/src/jit/compiler.js:211:72)
  at JitCompiler.Object.<anonymous>.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents (node_modules/packages/compiler/esm5/src/jit/compiler.js:189:35)
  at JitCompiler.Object.<anonymous>.JitCompiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:33443:37)
  at CompilerImpl.Object.<anonymous>.CompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (node_modules/packages/platform-browser-dynamic/esm5/src/compiler_factory.js:107:16)
  at TestingCompilerImpl.Object.<anonymous>.TestingCompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic-testing.umd.js:369:31)
  at TestBed.Object.<anonymous>.TestBed.compileComponents (node_modules/packages/core/esm5/testing/src/test_bed.js:355:23)
  at Function.Object.<anonymous>.TestBed.compileComponents (node_modules/packages/core/esm5/testing/src/test_bed.js:198:33)
  at src/pages/about/about.spec.ts:17:9
  at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:388:26)
  at AsyncTestZoneSpec.Object.<anonymous>.AsyncTestZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js:49:39)
  at ProxyZoneSpec.Object.<anonymous>.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:76:39)
  at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:387:32)
  at Zone.Object.<anonymous>.Zone.runGuarded (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:151:47)
  at runInTestZone (node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:141:25)
  at node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:80:13
  at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:388:26)
  at ProxyZoneSpec.Object.<anonymous>.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:39)
  at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:387:32)
  at Zone.Object.<anonymous>.Zone.run (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:138:43)
  at Object.testBody.length.done (node_modules/jest-zone-patch/index.js:51:29)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing and working with pages that are not in tabs, I found that a page that is displayed in tabs, can still be tested like a normal page.

```
import { async, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule, IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';

import { AppModule } from './../../app/app.module';
import { MyApp } from './../../app/app.component';

import { AboutPageModule } from './about.module';
import { AboutPage } from './about';

describe('About Page', () => {
    let fixture;
    let component;

    beforeEach(async(() => {                        // Need Async since we are using an external HTML/URL 
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [MyApp],
            schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA] ,
            imports: [
                IonicModule.forRoot(AboutPage),     // This page is in a tab, but does not matter for testing
                AboutPageModule
            ],
            providers: [
            ]
        }).compileComponents();                     // Need to compileComponents() as this is an external HTML file
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AboutPage);   // Create the Page for testing
        component = fixture.componentInstance;          // Get a reference to the created instance
    });

    afterEach( () => {
        component = null;
        fixture.destroy();
    })

    it ('should be created', () => {
        expect(component instanceof AboutPage).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

Therefore I simplified my test to the above code.  The NavComponent and NavParams are added by the Ionic generator and are not needed in the basic page, so I can remove them from the constructor call, and then I do not need to set them up in the test either.

EDIT: Another option is to leave the NavComponent and NavParams and inject mocks for them.  The Ionic project does have a small mock library for these that allows you to leave them in your code as they would normally be, and then use the mock to continue to test without referencing these controls since you are likely not testing these as they are injected.  You can then have the NavComponent and NavParams pass in specific data if you need to test what happens with special data.

Add the Mock Import to the test

```
import { PlatformMock, SplashScreenMock, StatusBarMock} from './../test-config/mocks-ionic';
```

Load the Mocks as providers:

```
    ...
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
           ...
            providers: [
                { provide: Platform, useClass: PlatformMock },
                { provide: SplashScreen, useClass: SplashScreenMock },
                { provide: StatusBar, useClass: StatusBarMock },
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));
```

Then the page can be called with the components in the constructor and be tested that it was created.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using Jest and also encountered "**can't resolve all parameters**" but for me it was another beast.

The first time I ran my test with Jest, it went all fine. Every successive runs fired the aforementioned error.

What **definitely solved the issue** was running jest without cache using: `jest --no-cache`.

I've been banging my head for so long before finding about that. I hope it will help anyone with the same issue. (I've tried the @Injectable() solutions thingy with no chance.)